# Foreach loop show value's only once if repeated

Tags: c#, razor, razor-2

I have a foreach loop in which the values are repeated and i would like to group the value's and out put values only once. my code looks like this

```
foreach (LoopItem i in GetLoop("Product.Prices")){
    var priceQuantity = "";
    if(i.GetInteger("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity") == 0){
        priceQuantity = "1";
    } else if(i.GetInteger("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity") >= 1){
        priceQuantity = i.GetString("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity");
    }   
    <!--@Translate(Ved, "VED")--> @priceQuantity <!--@Translate(Count, "STK")-->. - <!--@Translate(Count, "STK")-->. <!--@Translate(Price, "PRIS")-->. @i.GetValue("Ecom:Product.Prices.AmountFormatted")<br/> 
    }
```

which gives the following out put
   1 stk,
   1 stk,
   1 stk,
   12 stk,
   8 stk,
   8 stk,
   1 stk

i would like to output it as 
   1 stk,
   12 stk,
    8 stk

How can i achieve this output please help

Comment: Have you tried using a Dictionary to store your values that you've printed? You can then check if the value is already present in the Dictionary before printing it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = GetLoop("Product.Prices").GroupBy(x => x.Quantity).Select(x => x.First());
```

And then you can print result collection with your conditions.

```
    foreach (LoopItem i in result){
        var priceQuantity = "";
        if(i.GetInteger("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity") == 0){
            priceQuantity = "1";
        } else if(i.GetInteger("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity") >= 1){
            priceQuantity = i.GetString("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity");
        }   
        <!--@Translate(Ved, "VED")--> @priceQuantity <!--@Translate(Count, "STK")-->. - <!--@Translate(Count, "STK")-->. <!--@Translate(Price, "PRIS")-->. @i.GetValue("Ecom:Product.Prices.AmountFormatted")<br/> 
    }
```

But also you can do it in another way, using `HashSet<T>`

```
var sequence = GetLoop("Product.Prices");
var alreadyIn = new HashSet<T>();
foreach(var i in sequence)
{
        if(alreadyIn.Add(i))// Returns false if item was already in set
        {
           if(i.GetInteger("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity") == 0){
               priceQuantity = "1";
           }else if(i.GetInteger("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity") >= 1){
             priceQuantity = i.GetString("Ecom:Product.Prices.Quantity");
           }
           <!--@Translate(Ved, "VED")--> @priceQuantity <!--@Translate(Count, "STK")-->. - <!--@Translate(Count, "STK")-->. <!--@Translate(Price, "PRIS")-->. @i.GetValue("Ecom:Product.Prices.AmountFormatted")<br/> 
        }              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this take enumerable collection then

```
var collection = GetLoop("Product.Prices");

var firstItemsInGroup = from b in collection 
                 group b by b.Quantity into g
                 select g.First();
```

This will give you one item for quantity

Answer (score 0):

Use `Distinct()` like:

```
  foreach (LoopItem i in GetLoop("Product.Prices").Distinct())
```

Should work.